# Android HashMap Extract Different Objects

Tags: java, android, object, hashmap

I have a method (below) that accepts a HashMap to insert into a database.  The objects in the HashMap are a mixture of Strings, ints and doubles. I don't really care if they all go in the database as Strings because the work is finished with them.

The following code just doesn't work.  I get a NullPointerException as soon as it hits the first int.  I give all empty ints and doubles a value of 0 so they're not null, but when it hits that System.out.println method it throws the exception.  I'm probably missing something here and your help would be great.

```
public void insertQueTicket (HashMap<String, Object> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : queryValues.entrySet()) {
        String column = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue().toString();
        //contentValues.put(column, value);
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    //db.insert(QUETICKETS_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
02-19 21:40:12.409    3411-3411/com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms I/System.out﹕ 0.0
02-19 21:40:12.409    3411-3411/com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-19 21:40:12.419    3411-3411/com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d85b20)
02-19 21:40:12.429    3411-3411/com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 8% free 3646K/3940K, paused 4ms, total 9ms
02-19 21:40:12.429    3411-3411/com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms, PID: 3411
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms.DBController.insertQueTicket(DBController.java:214)
        at com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms.Activity_Main.SubmitTicketData(Activity_Main.java:105)
        at com.crudeoms.scalehauling.coms.Fragment_Ticket$1.onClick(Fragment_Ticket.java:198)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I figure it's the way I'm converting items such as int, double, etc.  Each line item in the queryValues Hashmap is , if that makes since.  Each variable has been previously converted from EditText fields to int, double or String.

I suppose I might have confusion on int vs. Integer and double vs. Double?

Comment: your printing code works fine without any errors.Will need the log cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was my fault.  You were correct the error was coming from somewhere else.  I was initializing my variables wrong.

You can't do this:

```
int one, two, three = 0;
```

You have to say:

```
int one = 0, two = 0, three = 0;
```

Everything was coming back null except the variables on the end which were the only variables getting assigned.

Thank you again for the help and quick response.

Answer (score 1):

"I get a NullPointerException as soon as it hits the first int" It looks like you tried to insert int primitive type in the HashMap. You should instead either convert them to Integer or String objects before inserting them in the HashMap. In brief the error lies elsewhere.